# how to order dictionary python (sorting)

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I use Python dictionary:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> a["w"] = {}
>>> a["a"] = {}
>>> a["s"] = {}
>>> a
{'a': {}, 's': {}, 'w': {}}
```

I need:

```
>>> a
{'w': {}, 'a': {}, 's': {}}
```

How can I get the order in which I filled the dictionary?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: You could use OrderedDict http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537308/6561141 for python 3.6 and above, dict maintains insertion ordering

Answer (score 17, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

> An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys were first
>   inserted. If a new entry overwrites an existing entry, the original
>   insertion position is left unchanged. Deleting an entry and
>   reinserting it will move it to the end.

```
>>> import collections
>>> a = collections.OrderedDict()
>>> a['w'] = {}
>>> a['a'] = {}
>>> a['s'] = {}
>>> a
OrderedDict([('w', {}), ('a', {}), ('s', {})])
>>> dict(a)
{'a': {}, 's': {}, 'w': {}}
```

Answer (score 3):

you should use `OrderedDict` instead of `Dict`.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html